# execute zle widget without binding it

Tags: zsh

I would like to execute a zle command without binding it to a key.
The only solution I currently see is something like this.

```
cmd() { RBUFFER="some text to enter into the prompt" }
zle -N cmd
bindkey '^]'
sleep 0.05 && xdotool key Control+bracketright
```

If I would source this piece it would directly execute the widget, but this is rather ugly.
Is there a way to execute the widget directly from inside the shell, or even from a script, without sourcing it?

EDIT:
what I maybe generally would like to have is a way to manipulate zle stuff like `RBUFFER`, `LBUFFER` etc. from any zsh script.

Comment: I found this too, and no I think it doesn't. Here again a zle command has to executed, by typing through a special internal prompt in the shell. AFAIK it can't be programmed, nor can it be executed inside a shell script. I read some stuff about `TRAPALRM`, which is cool, but the minimum possible time (as it looks) is 1 second, so the function will be called each second, and for my purpose that wouldn't be snappy enough tbh.

Comment: okay maybe it is a duplicate, essentially he asked for the same thing. I read a bit more through the discussion, and no one had a good answer, so maybe it is just impossible to achieve that without a keybinding.

Comment: I have troubles to understand your approach. `RBUFFER` etc. is only meaningful when there is something written on the command line ("zle is active"), but how do you want to execute a script then? If you want to prefill the commandline, maybe `print -z` will help you.

Comment: print -z also only works, when executed in the same env, so if I do `zsh -c print -z "bla"` it won't work. 
The thing is I just want to have 100% control over `zle` stuff, from external.

Currently I achieved this by reading a queue during trapalarm, and execute the read command.
A command e.g. could be `RBUFFER=bla; zle reset-prompt`. So externally I now can push something into the buffer and it is interpreted in `zle` context. But `TMOUT` can only be set to 1 second, and thats not snappy enough for me as said.

Comment: Ok, my last idea is that you might get some inspiration from syntax highlighting scripts, there are some different ones out there; _zsh-syntax-highlighting_ uses e.g. the `add-zle-hook-widget` functionality of zsh > 5.8.

Comment: Yeah I also looked at some hooks, but those are triggered on certain stuff which happens inside the shell, e.g. on key enter or something, which means it is triggered by events popped inside the shell. Since I want to have an external trigger, I don't think hooks will be of great help. Tho I probably have to check more, maybe I find something I could abuse for that. Thank you for your input so far :)